# How can I unban every member from a guild

Tags: discord.js

i was wondering if someone can share a code with me or message me on discord to help me --> Maniac#3833

i tried this code below.. and it failed.

```
if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'unbanall')) {

if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send('You don\'t have permissions to use this command')

  message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans => {
    bans.forEach(member => {
      message.guild.members.unban(member);
      message.channel.send(`Unbanned **${bans.size}** users`)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you using Discord.js V12?

Comment: Yes, I am using v12 @Jayke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fetchBans()` method returns a collection of `BanInfo`. So you need to do it this way:

```js
if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'unbanall')) {

if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send('You don\'t have permissions to use this command')

  message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans => {
    bans.forEach(banInfo => {
      message.guild.members.unban(banInfo.user);
    });
    message.channel.send(`Unbanned **${bans.size}** users`)
  })
}
```

Also, the message.channel.send() won't wait the forEach, so it will send it before all the members are banned.